# best way to backup a jailbroken iphone 3gs?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, backup

I want to be able to backup my apps, sources and themes so that i can still do restores without having to go through the whole process everytime. I am a tinkerer, and sometimes I break stuff. I need a way out!!

Comment: From my experience, there's no good way to do it. But I hope someone prove me wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out pkgbackup on cydia? It has worked for me.